# How to get autocomplete to work on form fields that have been created with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

In my app I have a form to which the user can add `tasks` without reloading the page. This is achieved through jQuery.

The task `description` input field is an [autocomplete field](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) that gets its data from a hidden div in the same HTML page.

The problem is that the autocomplete works as expected on all tasks that have been saved but *not* on the ones that have been created on the fly with jQuery and have not been saved yet.

My jQuery code is very simple:

```
$('input.description').autocomplete({
  source: $('#source').data('autocomplete-source')
});
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing here?

How can I get the autocomplete to work on newly created tasks that haven't been saved yet?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have a jquery to append task input to some element.

```
$('body').append(newInput);
```

So after that append you have to call the **autocomplete setup** again, because that autocomplete will only work for the elements that was created already when that function was called.

So your full code should be something like this:

```
$('body').append(newInput);
$('input.description').autocomplete({
  source: $('#source').data('autocomplete-source')
});
```

Comment: Ah yes. You are completely right! Shame on me. Quite obvious actually ;-) Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Tintin81 No problem, any time.